rewrite rule to rewrite or replace the prefix for ingress rule in kubernetes
I am struggling with making a rewrite/replace rule on nginx-ingress on kubernetes.
I want to replace the prefix https:///foo to https:///services/goo
Can anyone suggest the ingress file for this.
Thanks and Regards.

You can use the rewrite rule to replace the prefix in an ingress rule. The rewrite-target annotation is commonly used in ingress to replace the prefixes or perform other URL transformations before forwarding the request to the backend service.
Here is an example of an ingress configuration that replaces the prefix https://foo with https://services/goo using rewrite-target annotation.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 
kind: Ingress 
metadata: 
   name: my-ingress 
   annotations: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: https://services/goo/$1
spec: 
  rules: 
     - host: example.com
       http:
        paths:
        - path: /foo/?(.*)
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
             service:
               name: my-service
               port:
                 number: 80

In the above example the annotation -  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target is used to specify the replacement pattern. The $1 in the annotation refers to the captured group from the regular expression in the path field.
The path field defines a prefix match for the /foo/ path. When a request comes in that matches this path, the ingress controller will rewrite the URL to https://services/goo/$1, where $1 is the part of the url that comes after the  /foo/ prefix.
In this way if you access https://example.com/foo/some-path, the ingress controller will rewrite to https://services/goo/some-path and forward the request to backend service.
